# How to implement the wide and deep with ftrl optimizer in tensorflow without using estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the paper of [Wide & Deep Learning for Recommender Systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07792.pdf), Followthe-regularized-leader (FTRL) algorithm with L1 regularization is used as the optimizer for the wide part of the model, and AdaGrad optimizer is for the deep part.

Wheras [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/census_main.py#L65) teaches us how to build such a wide and deep model using this `tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` high level api. The handler of this [api](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNLinearCombinedClassifier) is as follows,

```
estimator = DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
    # wide settings
    linear_feature_columns= 
        [categorical_feature_a_x_categorical_feature_b],
    linear_optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(...),
    # deep settings
    dnn_feature_columns=[
        categorical_feature_a_emb, categorical_feature_b_emb,
        numeric_feature],
    dnn_hidden_units=[1000, 500, 100],
    dnn_optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(...),
    # warm-start settings
    warm_start_from="/path/to/checkpoint/dir")
```

Now what I want is to realize this wide and deep model with the ftrl and AdaGrad optimizer not using the `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`. Be specifically, I wonder whether the following works right as the `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`

```
loss = y_pred - y_label
optimizer = tf.train.FtrlOptimizer
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), var_list=var_ftrl)

optimizer2 = tf.train.AdaGradOptimizer
train_op2 = optimizer2.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(), var_list=var_adagrad)
```